# Is there a simple proof that $e^2$ is irrational using a positional numeral system?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, number-systems

My favorite proof that $e$ is irrational goes something like this.  Observe that we can write *any* real number $r$ as
$$
a \,+\, \frac{b_2}{2} \,+\, \frac{b_3}{3!} \,+\, \frac{b_4}{4!} \,+\, \frac{b_5}{5!} \,+\, \cdots
$$
where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and each $b_n\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.  This is the expansion of $r$ in the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), where $b_n$ is the $n$'th "digit". In particular,
$$
a \;=\; \lfloor r\rfloor\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_n = \big\lfloor n!\,(r-s_{n-1})\big\rfloor
$$
for each $n$, where $s_n$ denotes the $n$'th partial sum of the above series.

It is easy to see that $r$ is rational if and only if this expansion terminates.  Then $e$ must be irrational, since its expansion does not terminate:
$$
e \;=\; 2 \,+\, \frac{1}{2} \,+\, \frac{1}{3!} \,+\, \frac{1}{4!} \,+\, \frac{1}{5!} \,+\, \cdots
$$
**Question:** Can this proof somehow be modified to show that $e^2$ is irrational? It doesn't work straight off, since $2^n$ isn't in the range $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

I'm also curious whether there are any other cases in which irrationality of an interesting number can be proven using a [non-standard positional numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems).

Comment: There's an easy proof using the transcendence of $e$, so I'm guessing you're really interested in using this precise argument. Am I right?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I'm interested specifically in an argument along these lines.  I've modified the title of the post to make this more clear.

Comment: One may say that Liouville numbers are defined using an unconventionalnumber system where any nonterminating number with bounded digits is not only irrational, but in fact transcendental.

Comment: @RagibZaman How does that apply? We want to show $e^2$ irrational, but its square root $e$ is not rational.

Comment: @Ragib : Yeah we're trying to show that $e \neq \sqrt{ \frac ab}$ here essentially.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, Hagen, I've evidently gone crazy in my excitement. Please ignore my comments, and hail the Miami Heat!

Comment: I tried assuming that the expansion terminated, hence that $e^2 = C/N!$ for some integers $C$ and $N$. Then I tried to write $e^2 = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{2^k}{k!}$ to expect that for some $k$ large and prime there would be a problem...

Comment: Jim, I don't currently have the book with me, but I recall that "Making transcendence transparent" by Burger and Tubbs explores this in detail, as motivation for the transcendence argument. (Hope I'm not misremembering.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo That looks like a fantastic book.  I'll have to buy a copy!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@Robert Israel was very close.

Assume $e^2=p/q$. Rewrite as $qe-pe^{-1}=0$, or $$2q+{q-p\over2!}+{q+p\over3!}+{q-p\over4!}+\cdots=0$$ This isn't exactly in the form of the expansion in the first paragraph of the question, but the numerators are bounded in absolute value, which is more than enough to make the proof go through.

Comment: Wonderful!  After a few months, I had given up on this question ever being answered!

Answer (score 10):

Not quite $e^2$, but consider $x = a e + b/e$ for integers $a,b$ with $|b| \le a$.
Then $x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j/j!$ where $c_j = a+b$ when $j$ is even and $a-b$ when $j$ is odd.  Write $x = r + y$ where $r = \sum_{j = 0}^{a+b} c_j/j!$ is rational and $y = \sum_{j=a+b+1}^\infty c_j/j!$ is a non-terminating expansion in factorial base, and thus is irrational.  Therefore $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Very nice!  I suppose this is a special case of the following fact:  if $0\leq b_n < n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n/n!$ must be irrational.

Answer (score 4):

The usual elementary proof that $e$ is irrational works also for $e^2$.

Suppose that $e^2$ is rational. 
We know that 
$$ e^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}. $$

Let $q\ge2$ be a positive integer, and let $Q=2^q$. 
If $q$ is sufficiently large then $\dfrac{Q!}{2^{Q-q+1}}\cdot e^2$ is an integer. (Notice that the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $\dfrac{Q!}{2^{Q-q+1}}$ is $q-2$.)

Now consider 
$$
\frac{Q!}{2^{Q-q+1}}\cdot e^2
-\sum_{k=0}^Q \frac{Q!}{2^{Q-q}} \cdot \frac{2^{k-1}}{k!}
=\sum_{k=Q+1}^\infty \frac{2^{k-Q-1}Q}{(Q+1)(Q+2)\ldots k} .
$$
The left-hand side is an integer and the right-hand side is in $(0,1)$.
Contradiction.

Comment: Nice elementary proof. I have found somewhat tricky to proof that the second term of the LHS is in fact an integer -> The 2-adic valuation is positive for each fraction.

Comment: I think this is nice but the right side is $\displaystyle >\dfrac{Q}{Q+1}+\dfrac{2Q}{(Q+1)(Q+2)}>1$?

Comment: Okay, so we have $\displaystyle \sum_{k\ge Q+1}\dfrac{2^{k-Q-1}Q}{(Q+1)(Q+2)\cdots k}=1\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{2Q}{Q+2}+\dfrac{4Q}{(Q+2)(Q+3)}+\cdots=1$ but it's still $>1$ and a contradiction. I like this one because it can be extended to every $n$. So thank you for this!

Comment: @W. Wongcharoenbhorn I do not see how you generalize. Please, can you give ant hints?

Comment: @joaopa I'm sorry I can't generalize it. Just my misunderstanding.